# aggdraw cannot load font (no text renderer)

Tags: python, fonts, drawing, aggdraw

I've installed [aggdraw](http://effbot.org/zone/pythondoc-aggdraw.htm) on OS X 10.8 using Apple's stock Python (2.7.2) using [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/jsundram/6022938/58fc8f26885c2a2e445f548685b880eb243bfb05). Before doing so, I used homebrew to install freetype, and I modified aggdraw's setup.py to point to my freetype installation (`FREETYPE_ROOT = "/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/"` on line 32).

Despite all of this, when I try to load a font, I get:

```
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
      font = Font('black', '/Library/Fonts/Georgia.ttf')
IOError: cannot load font (no text renderer)
```

test.py looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image
from aggdraw import Draw, Brush, Pen, Font

size = 500, 500
img = Image.new("RGBA", size)
draw = Draw(img)
draw.rectangle((0, 0) + size, Brush((255, 255, 255), opacity=255))
draw.setantialias(True)
font = Font('black', '/Library/Fonts/Georgia.ttf')
draw.text((100, 100), "hello, world", font)
draw.flush()
img.save("test.png")
```

What do I need to do in order to load and use fonts in aggdraw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my `FREETYPE_ROOT`. Line 32 of aggdraw's setup.py should be as follows: `FREETYPE_ROOT = "/usr/local"`

After changing that line, rebuilding and reinstalling, the test.py script above works fine.

I've updated my [install script](https://gist.github.com/jsundram/6022938) to apply that patch.