# Installing Aggdraw with Freetype support

Tags: python, freetype, aggdraw

I'm trying to compile the Aggdraw drawing module for Python 2,7 with Freetype text rendering support in Windows. Problem is, even though I'm doing everything by the book I still get the error message that there is no font renderer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BIGKIMO\Desktop\fdsfdf.py", line 9, in <module>
    font = Font('black', r'C:\Windows\Fonts\Georgia.ttf')
IOError: cannot load font (no text renderer)
```

I've read previous posts about it, so did these steps:

1. Downloaded precompiled version of Freetype 2.3.5
2. Pointed the FREETYPE_ROOT variable in the setup.py script to the freetype folder path ("C:/.../Desktop/freetype-2.3.5")
3. Installed aggdraw by typing `cd path/to/folder/of/setup.py`, and then `python setup.py install`

The setup script seems to accept the freetype location I give it and does not complain about freetype being disabled, so I would've thought that Aggdraw Freetype support got installed.

I've tried the same on a Mac, using the 64-bit version of Aggdraw, compiled Freetype, compiled Aggdraw with link to Freetype, yet still won't let me draw text.

Here is the code I use to test the text rendering, though that shouldnt be the problem:

```
from PIL import Image
from aggdraw import Draw, Brush, Pen, Font

size = 500, 500
img = Image.new("RGBA", size)
draw = Draw(img)
draw.rectangle((0, 0) + size, Brush((255, 255, 255), opacity=255))
draw.setantialias(True)
font = Font('black', r'C:\Windows\Fonts\Georgia.ttf')
draw.text((100, 100), "hello, world", font)
draw.flush()
img.save("test.png")
```

What am I doing wrong? Why would it let me compile with a link to Freetype, yet still complain about no font renderer?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps posting sample code and the error logs/output would assist others in answering your question?

Comment: Are you sure the Freetype installation dir is the correct value for `FREETYPE_ROOT`? (See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770413/aggdraw-cannot-load-font-no-text-renderer))

Comment: Thanks both for your answeres, and apologies for the delay. I've updated the post now with code example and error msg. 
@PythonNut I had already read the post you linked to, but the answer in that post only applies to Mac or Linux I think, since "usr/local" is not a valid Windows directory. It also doesn't make sense why that would work, because what the `setup.py` script does is append the FREETYPE_ROOT variable with "/include", "/include/freetype2", and "/lib" - all folders within the freetype folder I pointed to. 
(Note: my freetype folder is located on the desktop, nowhere system wide)